# How to set variable in preg_replace (html syntax)?

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$con = preg_replace('#(<input type="text"[^>]+?>)#', '<input type="hidden" name="dog" value="$a">${1}', $content);
```

How to set value as variable? This what I've got is not correct ($a, syntax?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you need $a or the contents of the variable $a

```
'<input type="hidden" name="dog" value="'.$a.'">${1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ${1}, I think it should just be $1. That's what I always use and it seems to work.

Comment: ${1} - it work. I will add $a as value -> <input type="hidden" value="$a"> - this is not correct.